# Laravel 8.0 best practice for setting up route for admin and non-admin role

Tags: php, laravel

I have these 2 users in my system (admin and non-admin) and I'm reading the **Laravel Docs** to know the proper and best practice in knowing how to separate the admin to non-admin, and the separation of roles would reflect on the **Laravel Blade**.

I was familiar with setting up the user authentication using the `php artisan make:auth` command in the lower version of Laravel. Reading the current docs of Laravel (8.0), it seems like this command is not present in the current documentation anymore. It seems like Laravel would like to promote **Laravel Breeze** rather than set up your own (or manual) user role authentication.

Now, I do not like to download a package for creating a **user role authentication** without knowing how to set it up manually.

Is there a simple, effective, and secure way of authenticating the roles of the user of the system manually?

Comment: In my opinion, admin and non-admin determine what a user can and can't do, so I would use [authorisation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization) to authorise an action when it's happening instead of having a rigid separation of user types. The are also [blade helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#via-blade-templates) for this

Comment: I once come across the Laravel Authorization. I would check on this. Thanks.

Comment: It seems like my go-to option would be to use authorization after all. But it confuses me which exactly would I use within the system. Whether **gates** or **policies**

Comment: Personal preference is policies but if you only have a couple of basic actions you need to authorise then gates are probably good enough. The docs describe the difference as : *Think of gates and policies like routes and controllers. Gates provide a simple, closure based approach to authorization while policies, like controllers, group logic around a particular model or resource*

Comment: @apokryfos the system I'm currently developing were relatively small. It might be best for me to just use the gate if that's the case.